# how to get json_encode php in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I want to send this $data

```
if($query == true)
{
   
    $data = array(
        'status'=> true,
        'result' => 1
       
    );
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

then I want to retrieve the data

```
success: function(data) {
    console.log(data.status);
}
```

In the console is `undefined`, but if I `console.log(data)`, the data is called.

Comment: PHP sends JSON, which is textual data exchange format. You've to parse the received string to a live JS object, see [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

Comment: Or make your server return this with an appropriate `Content-Type` header, or tell jQuery that you are expecting JSON via the `dataType` parameter.

Comment: The console will display the JSON but as a string. Like `{"status":true,"result":1}`. If that were already parsed into an object, it would look different. You can see the difference by logging an object: run `console.log({ status: true, result:1 })` and you will see it looks very different.

Comment: Put `header("Content-Type: application/json");` above your `echo` command and jQuery should parse the JSON reply into an object, like CBroe says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) Either use [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

```
success: function(data) {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(data.status);
    console.log(data.result);
}
```

b) Or in your ajax request add this only:

```
dataType: 'json'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse json data to use in javascript.

```
success: function(data) {

  if ( typeof data !=="undefined" ) {
     var result = JSON.parse(data);
     console.log(result);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

your data might still be a string, and you need to parse it to object first. You can use `JSON.parse`.

```js
let json = '{"test":"val"}';
console.log(JSON.parse(json).test); // will output val
```